# How to go about native packaging with PhoneGap for a simple one page application?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I have a simple one page web application. Due to some reasons, my client wants to package this as a native app for iOS and Andriod. This application does not intend to use any of the device's capability (such as camera etc.). It just needs to be packaged so that it runs on the mobile device as a native app rather than the browser.

My question is if I use PhoneGap to package this app, can I simply upload the zip file as is on phonegap and download the packages for these devices? Or I would need to go through the process of creating phonegap app?

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow some process for it. You have to add `config.xml` and make some changes in it as per your requirement. And nothing else.

Make zip file of your HTML, CSS, Config.xml.

Refer [**Phonegap Build Documents**](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/3.1.0/#googtrans%28en%29)